# Cannot connect to SQL\Express with pyodbc/pymssql and Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, pyodbc, pymssql

I'm having issues connecting to a working SQL\Express database instance using Robot Framework's DatabaseLibrary.

If I use either `Connect To Database` with previously defined variables or `Connect To Database Using Custom Params` with a connection string, I get the following results:

- **pyodbc:** `('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')`
- **pymssql:**: `InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.`

The connection string I'm using is the following: `'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost\SQLExpress;UID=sa;PWD=mypass;DATABASE=MyDb'`

I copied several examples from guides and tutorials and all of them yield the same result, so my guess is that there is something wrong on my end, but I just can't figure out what. I can access the database using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio just fine, so the database is running.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the database from a plain Python script without using Robot Framework? BTW, be aware that pymssql is not an ODBC access layer so the connection string you posted will almost certainly not work with pymssql.

Comment: Might be irrelevant to you, but at our work place, we have a number of MSSQL services running on one machine (08, 12, 16) and the problem was we had an overlap of ports and the interface was getting confused. As for the difference in error messages with different interfaces, pymssql basically always says that error for everything. The Keyword I used was: `Connect To Database Using Custom Params    pymssql    ${DBConnect}` where `${DBConnect}` contained `database`, `user`, `Password`, `host` and `port`

Comment: I was able to connect using your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to connect using @Goralight approach: `Connect To Database Using Custom Params pymssql ${DBConnect}` where `${DBConnect}` contained `database`, `user`, `Password`, `host` and `port`